Keyboard event HooksCallback
public class KeyBoardInputHandler
{
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc? _proc;
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    public KeyBoardInputHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key Set: KeyBoardInputHandler variables ");
        try
        {
            _proc = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(HookCallback);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Not Set: KeyBoardInputHandler variables _proc {ex}");
        }
        try
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Not Set: KeyBoardInputHandler variables _hookID {ex} ");
        }
    }


    public static void CleanUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key Checked: CleanUp ");
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }


    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up hook...");
        using var curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        using var curModule = curProcess.MainModule;
        IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(curModule?.ModuleName);
        IntPtr hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, moduleHandle, 0);
        if (hookID == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to set hook. Error code: {errorCode}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hook set successfully.");
        }
        return hookID;
    }


    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Checked: HookCallback ");
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Console.WriteLine($"Key Pressed: {vkCode}");
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start listening for keyboard events. Press ESC to stop.");
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for keyboard events...");

    // Create one instance of KeyBoardInputHandler
    KeyBoardInputHandler handler;

    do
    {
        handler = new();
        // Wait for a key press
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);


        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            break; // Exit the loop
        }
    } while (true);

    // Clean up the hook when the user presses ESC
    KeyBoardInputHandler.CleanUp();
    Console.WriteLine("Stopped listening for keyboard events.");
}

the HoolCallback is not triggering
private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key Checked: HookCallback ");
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Pressed: {vkCode}");
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return 0;
    }
}

When I click any key in the keyboard
it logs this when I press any key in keyboard
Press any key to start listening for keyboard events. Press ESC to stop.
Listening for keyboard events...
Key Set: KeyBoardInputHandler variables 
Setting up hook...
Hook set successfully.
Key Set: KeyBoardInputHandler variables 
Setting up hook...
Hook set successfully.
Key Checked: CleanUp 
Stopped listening for keyboard events.

I'm trying to capture the keyboard events when any key is pressed and it should return the log in console "key is pressed" but the Hook callback function is not triggering, and the code is not showing any errors I debugged tried running application on administrator, give permission , chatGpt, all, nothing works any one know what's the issue?
